# Capybara server & browser error with no trace on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5

For some reason one of my cucumber tests seem to fail both on the poltergeist driver and from the rails server.

I am getting a full trace on the browser crash but almost nothing on the server side.

When I open the Capybara screenshot I just see

> Internal Server Error
>   undefined method `name` for nil:NilClass

When I tail the test.log

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms (Elasticsearch: 0.0ms)

(And no trace)

I have tried

- to set `config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true`
- the `b` flag (but it's only showing the detailed trace for the Capybara error
- (my config level is set to :debug already in my environment file)

How can I get the full backtrace on the server side ?

EDIT

- Capybara 2.13.0
- Rails 5.0.2
- everything commented in backtrace_silencers

Comment: Just a few random thoughts: try removing Rails silencers (see `config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb`) or perhaps this might be some log flushing issue? What Rails version are we talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got something from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21310317/2832282) !

So the solution was to allow rescuing the exception in ActionController::Base. In my env file I had the following lines that were misleading

```
# There are two ways to allow Rails to rescue exceptions:
#
# 1) Tag your scenario (or feature) with @allow-rescue
#
# 2) Set the value below to true. Beware that doing this globally is not
# recommended as it will mask a lot of errors for you!
#
ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false
```

And by adding the @allow-rescue tag I got more comprehensive error trace showing in my `test.log`, along with a frontend error view

Comment: This was really helpful! Had been struggling with this for 1 hour.

Comment: I just came back to this answer that I have upvoted some time ago. I wish I could upvote it again!

Answer (score 1):

If you (like me) do not use Cucumber but Capybara [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10108727/767845) might help you, too.

In `config/environments/test.rb` set

```
config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
```